# Versioned entites with Hibernate with a new row for every version

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

I'd like to implement the following versioning strategy with Hibernate: For every update of my entity, Hibernate should not update the existing row but insert a new row with the same id but a version column incremented by one.

Thus the primary key in the database is a composed key consisting of the entity id and the version number.

As I understand, putting a `@version` annotation on a property thus increments this property on every save but still updates the existing row and there does not seem to be a configuration option to get the behavior I want.

There's also [Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html) but it's not usable for my use case.

*Background:*
I want to implement a simple review workflow. Users can update entities but they are shown to the public only after a review. So I might have a "reviewed" boolean column and show the entity version with the highest version number that is reviewed.

Comment: Sorry. My first paragraph was wrong. I wrote column where I wanted to write row.

Comment: If no one knows of such a feature, I think you will have to write the whole logic as part of your application.